# How can I stop Gradle task execution in Android Studio?

Tags: gradle, android-studio

Is there a legitimate way of Gradle task(s) execution stopping in Android Studio?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as of May 2016. And then it goes OutOfMemoryException, even when the heap space is set to "4g"

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can call `./gradlew --stop` in a terminal and it will kill all Gradle processes.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Comment: Works well to force stop any gradle process, no matter which step is currently running. It's a shame that (as of Android Studio 2.2.2) the "stop" button in AS is not able to achieve the same thing...

Comment: i got a permission denied, even when running with root, on then mac.

Comment: that does not help in case the gradle is hanging up, only killing the process of Android Studio and then restarting it helps

Answer (score 48):

No, Gradle (as of this writing, v1.10) has a limitation that you can't cancel tasks through its tooling API, which is what Android Studio uses to communicate with its daemon. You can track the progress of this at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59464 . It's also preventing progress on something else we'd like to be able to do, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59965

In the meantime about all you can do is to go through your OS and kill the Gradle processes manually, which is a little painful and messy. It's possible that it could leave your build in some intermediate bad state which would mess up future incremental compiles, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: In that case, they should not give a Cancel button while executing gradle tasks.

Comment: Even if the issue was marked as "released" on Dec 2014, as of Nov 2015 I still have this very same bug. OMG, Android Studio is just horrendous.

Comment: As mentioned below, the --stop flag now works for this.

Comment: It's June 2016 and the Cancel still doesn't work as expected. In the thread mentioned in this answer they say they've implemented fixes for that, but I don't see a big difference in practice...

Comment: *kill the Gradle processes*? What's the name of a Gradle process?

Comment: 2021 and still not working as expected

Answer (score 36):

With Android Studio 1.3.2 a kill button appears when the gradle is building on the very bottom of the IDE screen.

[image: build kill button]

It doesn't seem to do anything, but at least there's something to push. Wheee! :D

Comment: android studio overall does a lot of bullshit that cant be turned off..

Comment: Now the "stopping" process is not stopping

Comment: That's a fake button, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: For me both 'gradlew --stop' command in the terminal and kill button in the bottom as shown by @Scott Biggs, worked.Thank you. Note: I didn't use './' before 'gradlew --stop' command.

Answer (score 9):

Quitting Android studio is another way it'll kill the gradle daemon or if it's hung deploying to Android device unplugging the device can halt the process (neither are ideal solutions)

Comment: Well my AS will stop functioning on quit when a Gradle task is running. It still seems responsive but it does not update the window,

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Rami Kuret and Flavio Faria.

You can call **.\gradlew --stop** in a Terminal and it will kill all Gradle processes in Android Studio for Windows OS.

You can find the terminal at the left bottom of your Android Studio for Windows.

[image: Screenshot of ...]

Answer (score 5):

This is just something quick I found out. If you want to end the process, you can also:

1. Go into Task Manager by right-clicking the taskbar then going to "Task Manager" or simply by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>
2. Then ending the Java process that's running.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When **every other method** fails just use:

```
ps -A | grep gradle | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs kill -9
```

to get the list of every process with a 'gradle' keywork and kill it forcefully.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but now with Android Studio 1.2, you can cancel current gradle task by quitting Android Studio, it'll open a Confirm exit dilog says there's a background running task, choose Exit, then there will be another dialog to cancel background task, choose Yes and gradle task will be canceled without quitting studio.

Remember to clean project before run other build task, or something might be messed up.

(I'm on Mac OS X)

Comment: On Windows it's similar. Quit Android Studio when gradle is running, answer "Exit", then answer "No". After that a gradle will stop compiling.

Comment: @CoolMind lately, if I do so, Android Studio freeze and show a black screen. I even have to reboot Windows for it to compile again...

Comment: @DanChaltiel, maybe, it happens sometimes (at my computer Android Studio hasn't freezed). Did you clean and rebuild a project after stopping gradle? Or Android Studio doesn't allow this? Sorry, if this bug remains.

Comment: @CoolMind Thx for replying, I even made a [question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118223/android-studio-1-5-1-cannot-build).

Comment: @DanChaltiel hm, it looks like Stankovitch recommended there to install 2 Android Studios. Sorry for a question, may a problem be in Java?

Comment: @CoolMind nop, everything was fine a moment ago. I'm trying some ORM libraries though, but sometimes they build. The new version of Android studio didn't resolve anything.

Answer (score 3):

Just execute `.\gradlew --stop` in the terminal which is located on the bottom of the Android Studio. After it kills the Gradle process, clean the project and rerun the project.

See the image for more information:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an Android Studio plugin for that: *[GradleStop](https://github.com/shchurov/GradleStop)*

It will just add a "gradle stop" command and menu item which will call `./gradlew --stop`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a "legitimate" way but this is what i do.

1. Click on Gradle Sync while your build process is ongoing.
2. Android Studio will warn you with something like "Continue with Project Closing?". Click yes.

The build process will be cancelled and the gradle Sync operation will begin which is relatively quicker (as compared to waiting for the whole build process to complete, as i have a project with MANY library modules)

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was:

Go to your project → *graddle-wrapper.properties* (Gradle version)

Then edit the distributionURl to the version you want. Here's a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy existing ways to stop it without killing the process.

The first one is that you *load two projects* with Android Studio, and when you close your project, the Gradle building project, it will close immediately.

The second one is simply click on the *file* and click <kbd>Close project</kbd> and it will stop instantly.

The benefits of these method is you don't need to wait too much to start Android Studio again.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the *studio.exe* process from [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) and then *restart* your machine. This is the only thing that is working for me.

If you kill every related process and don't restart the machine, you can't run or build your app because it will say "Another gradle instance running".

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Studio 3.0, the little red cross button next to the Gradle build status indicator bar seems to be working!

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, go to the *Run* dialog by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `taskkill /f /im studio64.exe`. That will kill [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) and stop [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle).

Comment: just reboot your machine xD