# How to stop a gradle sync if a certain condition is met

Tags: android, gradle

I have a `doNecessaryJob` task that depends on `preProcessing` task. If a certain condition in `preProcessing` is true, I want to stop the sync right away. How do I do that?

Part of my gradle is here:

```
task preProcessing() {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
    Pattern pattern
    if (tskReqStr.contains("assemble"))
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else
        pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tskReqStr)
    if (matcher.find()) {
        // do processing here
    } else {
        println "Error, stopping the sync."
        // !STOP THE GRADLE SYNC HERE DUE TO ERROR!
    }
}
task doNecessaryJob() {
    dependsOn preProcessing

    // do necessary processing here that depends on variables from preProcessing task
}
```

I checked other solutions here in SO but all seem to point to the command line solution such as [How to stop Gradle task execution in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184794/how-to-stop-gradle-task-execution-in-android-studio/32957759).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I used `GradleException` like so:

```
task preProcessing() {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
    Pattern pattern
    if (tskReqStr.contains("assemble"))
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else
        pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tskReqStr)
    if (matcher.find()) {
        // do processing here
    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Error, stopping the sync.")  // <--- THE FIX
    }
}
```